# How to go through a list and count numbers only?

Tags: javascript, list

how can I go through a list and make the computer check if it's a number, if it is a number, I want to count and move on until the end and then show the result.

for example if I had an array:

```
 var myArray = [1,2,a,4];
```

What I did was I would first split my array:

```
var splitted = myArray.toString()split(",").join(" ");
```

and then I used the for loop to go through each splitted value  and count it if it is a number(or a string) and then show the result in a the appropriate box:

```
 for(i=0;i<splitted.length; i+=1)
 {
 if(isNaN(splitted[i])===true)
 {
 document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value = splitted[i];
 }

else
{
document.getElementById("resultNumberCount").value = splitted[i];
```

but with this code I keep getting the last number that appears in my list and the last string that appears in my list to show up as a result in my boxes. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to show? If you want to show count, where is your counter?

Comment: you are overwriting document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value, do you want to display all numbers then you need different structure

Comment: what means *count*? a result of `3` or `7`?

Comment: I want to show the total number of numbers and strings in a list/array. For example in this case, my total number count would be 3 because there are 3 numbers in this list and my total word/string/character count would be 1 because there is only one "a". document.getElementById("resultNumberCount").value: is where the number count result should show and document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value: is where the word count result should show.

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `isNaN` and count.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 'a', 4],
    result = myArray.reduce(function (s, a) {
        return s + !isNaN(a);
    }, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [1,2,a,4];
var result = 0;
for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  result += !isNaN(+myArray[i]) ? myArray[i] : 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: yeah I agree that would really help thanks anyways though

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

myArray.forEach(function(item){
 if(!isNaN(Number(item))){
   count ++;
  }
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, if you already have an array, why would you transform it into a string, then split it, then join it again to another string? you're not looping over the array items but over the string characters. this will lead to all sorts of problems when your input changes.

then, `isNaN(splitted[i])===true` checks if the current item of the array is NOT a number, so  you should ignore those instead of using them.

finally, you're not doing any sum anywhere, just assigning each item in turn to the value of the "resultNumberCount" tag. That's why, at the end of the process you just see whatever value was last in the array (or, actually, string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map function` to count number of `integers`

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 'a', 4];
var numbers = 0;
myArray.map(function (a) {
if (Number(a))
   numbers++;
});
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to split your array 
And just concatenate the values

```js
 var myArray = [1,2,"a",4];
 var countNum = 0;
 var countNaN = 0;
 
 for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i+=1){
  if(isNaN(myArray[i])){
    document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value += myArray[i];
    countNaN++;
    
  }else{
    document.getElementById("resultNumberCount").value += myArray[i];  
    countNum++;
    
  }
}
console.log(countNaN);
console.log(countNum);
```

```html
<input id="resultNumberCount" type="text" disabled >
<input id="resultWordCount" type="text" disabled  >
```

**EDIT:**

If you want only the total:

```js
var myArray = [1,2,"a",4];
 var countNum = 0;
 var countNaN = 0;
 
 for(i=0;i<myArray.length; i+=1){
  if(isNaN(myArray[i])){
    
    countNaN++;
    
  }else{
    
    countNum++;
    
  }
}
document.getElementById("resultNumberCount").value = countNum;  
document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value = countNaN;
console.log(countNaN);
console.log(countNum);
```

```html
<input id="resultNumberCount" type="text" >
<input id="resultWordCount" type="text" >
```

Comment: Your code works but instead of showing the count of strings or numbers, it literally shows all the strings and all the numbers. Can you see a way to make it show the  count  and not the numbers or strings literally

Comment: Just when the for has finished do this `document.getElementById("resultWordCount").value = countNaN;` and `document.getElementById("resultNumberCount").value = countNum  `

Comment: I tried even tried to make changes but with the new code it's giving me strange list of numbers now "01284783" or "0000111" and etc

Comment: did you see my edit in the answer? with that you show only the total, is that what you need right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var a = [1, 2, 'c', 4];
console.log(a.filter(function(value){
    return !isNaN(value);
}).length)
```